# How To Redirect Non Existing URL's to the HomePage, When my site is in a Sub-directory....?

Tags: .htaccess

I had this .htaccess code which worked fine when my site and its files were in the home root folder, but I changed to a new host that already had domains on it, so my site is now in a SUBDIRECTORY and the following code no longer works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MyDomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ http://www.MyDomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

How do I modify it to make it work, do I need to include the subdirectory name in it? Right now if I typed in a non existing url "MyDomain.com/blahblah567 ....it just shows "page not found" type of thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How To Redirect Non Existing URL's to the HomePage

This will be enough:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/
```

OR using `mod_rewrite` in your subdir/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That didnt work, cause I already have A Redirect code in the .htaccess file, "Redirect 301 /-Pies http://www.pies/4819.html"    ....So now when they go to MyDomain.com/-Pies, it redirects them to the homepage! So its overruling my currently existing code for redirecting custom links.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my comment after you posted your comment.

Comment: You need to place this rule after your existing rules.

Comment: You probably don't understand how URL rewrite works. Post your complete existing .htaccess by editing your question so that I can investigate.